# How to convert string to date - mmddyyyy

Tags: c#

This could be very easy question. But I was unable to get the answer.
I have a date in string format like **mmddyyyy**.
How to convert this to date.

**EDIT**

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MMddyyyy",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I am getting an exception

> *System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: @OndrejJanacek-  did not work. `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`

Comment: @NewDeveloper What is your string by the way?

Comment: Yes, show us your string.

Answer (score 7):

use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(yourString, "MMddyyyy",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 4):

[`mm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#mmSpecifier) is for minutes, [`MM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MM_Specifier) is for months.

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method like;

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MMddyyyy",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Take a look at [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

It's too important to specify the invariant culture to ensure that the Gregorian calendar is used - if you use the *current system culture* then it could use a different calendar system.

Answer (score 2):

I think you did not search the internet properly. You could easily find an answer.

Use `Datetime.Parse()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/1k1skd40.aspx

From MSDN

> DateTime.Parse Method (String)
>
> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent.

Comment: I get 1 System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` exception

Comment: Than you have your date in an unsupported format and you should propably look at other answers if they are any more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have basically two options for this. `DateTime.Parse()` and `DateTime.ParseExact()`

First,

```
DateTime oDate = DateTime.Parse(string s);
```

Second,

```
DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(loadedString, "d", null);
```

"d" stands for the short date pattern and null specifies that the current culture should be used for parsing the string.